# Trouble using stsadm -o MigrateUser

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, stsadm

My organization is moving from one active diretory to another (new Domain). We are migrating the users first. As a test I am trying to run the MigrateUser command and getting a "cannot complete this action, please try again". Here is the command I am using:

stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin domainA\johnd -newlogin domainB\jDoe

The command won't work,  I get "Cannot complete this action."

The domains are two-way trusted.

Any ideas?

Bismarck

Comment: any error in the event log? also include the ignoresidhistory in your command them try.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved.  Unbeknownst to me the stsadm environment variable path was pointing to the 60-hive which was updating wss 2.0 databases.  I changed it to the 12-hive and it works now.

Bismarck